# How do you go about finding a new job after wasting several months not doing any useful?

Tags: new-job, job-change, work-experience

So basically i wasted 18 months trying to setup a business and it didn't work out.
I've had the 2 years experience prior to it in the same field.

So how will it affect the chances of finding a new job? I mean do you just mention on the resume that you did 18 months doing a business that failed, or you just mention the 2 years experience prior to that.

If i mention the 2 years experience only, won't recent experience hold more preference over the one that was acquired 18 months ago.

I am confused right now, what would be the good way to go about this issue?

Comment: Can't you just state on your CV "Date to - date from: Self Employed" and then state the tasks you performed and technologies used?  It saves a gap and you can then talk around what you did (rather than the business failing" if you happen to get to interview.  If asked, you can then just say, "I realised that I prefer to work for someone rather than be self employed".  Or something like that :)

Comment: This site is so full of [questions about an employment gap](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+gap) that I have a hard time picking an exact duplicate. But surely your answer is already in one of those.

Comment: I had a business fail and I learned so much from that.  Put it on your resume.

Comment: see also: [I worked for a company affiliated with a very publicly failed project. Should I take it off my resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17070/168)

Comment: You didn't waste 18 months, you learned some different, but very valuable lessons.  Leverage that.

Comment: Did your business have a name? You may have been self-employed but you still worked for the business.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is answerable by more than a very short opinion, so that might make it a bad question, but it certainly isn't a duplicate of the above posted question.