# Should I join a company whose website says it's the "No 1 Python development company" in *city*?

Tags: interviewing

I recently got an offer to join a start-up in my city (prefer not to name it) as a Python developer. Their website says they are the "best Python development company" in my city. This seems a little distasteful to me and I know there are better companies/start-ups out there.

Will this hurt my chances at future employers? Will they think less of this start-up when I am interviewing for them and they google the name and find out it touts itself as such?

I am in India, by the way.

Comment: So you are worried about the company you will join after the company which you have not joined yet?

Comment: @PagMax - Am I going to stay in this company forever? Maybe. I don't know. But should I be so short-sighted that I won't even consider what future implications it may have on my career? I don't think so.

Comment: Of all the things a company can do wrong, them exaggerating a bit in marketing should be the least of your worries.

Comment: @HariKamdar No you should not be shortsighted but your decision to join this company should not be based on what the next company may or may not think about the claims by present company which may or may not be true. Your decision should be based on what is the current company offering you and if that appeals to YOU and appeals to you NOW.

Comment: Related question featuring a more extreme example of company image: [I worked for a company affiliated with a very publicly failed project. Should I take it off my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17070)

Answer (score 4):

That company is using a marketing term.  These types of term are used by almost all businesses all over the world.  You've heard or seen them already and probably didn't pay any attention to it.

"The  is the most comfortable, quiet car you'll every drive."
or
" yogurt is made with special active, cultures, ingredients that only we use to get you the best tasting yogurt you've every had."

I seriously doubt any company will hold a slogan from another company, that you had nothing to do about, against you or your skills.

I wouldn't give it a second thought.